# How do I strip the comma from the end of a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

How do I strip comma from the end of a string?  I tried

```
awk = subprocess.Popen([r"awk", "{print $10}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
awk_stdin = awk.communicate(uptime_stdout)[0]
print awk_stdin
temp = awk_stdin
t = temp.strip(",")
```

also tried `t = temp.rstrip(",")`, both don't work.

---

This is the code:

```
uptime = subprocess.Popen([r"uptime"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
uptime_stdout = uptime.communicate()[0]
print uptime_stdout

awk = subprocess.Popen([r"awk", "{print $11}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
awk_stdin = awk.communicate(uptime_stdout)[0]
print repr(awk_stdin)
temp = awk_stdin
tem = temp.rstrip("\n")
logfile = open('/usr/src/python/uptime.log', 'a')
logfile.write(tem + "\n")
logfile.close()
```

---

This is the output:

```
 17:07:32 up 27 days, 37 min,  2 users,  load average: 5.23, 5.09, 4.79

5.23,
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uptime.py", line 21, in ?
    tem = temp.rstrip("\n")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Comment: Are you sure there's only `,`'s at the end of the string?

Comment: could you show us what `temp` is?

Comment: My first guess is that you string is not ending with a comma, but rather as a trailing newline. Could you post the EXACT output of awk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say

```
awk = subprocess.Popen([r"awk", "{print $11}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
awk_stdout = awk.communicate(uptime_stdout)[0]
```

then the output of the awk process is printed to stdout (e.g. a terminal).
`awk_stdout` is set to `None`. `awk_stdout.rstrip('\n')` raises an `AttributeError` because `None` has no attribute called `rstrip`.

When you say

```
awk = subprocess.Popen([r"awk", "{print $11}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
awk_stdout = awk.communicate(uptime_stdout)[0]
```

then nothing is printed to stdout (e.g. the terminal), and `awk_stdout` gets the output of the `awk` command as a string.

Comment: cool, that worked,
awk = subprocess.Popen([r"awk", "{print $11}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: @kris, I suggest you accept this answer then. +1 for catching it, ~unutbu.

Answer (score 7):

Err, how about the venerable:

```
if len(str) > 0:
    if str[-1:] == ",":
        str = str[:-1]
```

On second thought, `rstrip` itself should work fine, so there's something about the string you're getting from `awk` that's not quite what you expect. We'll need to see that.

---

I suspect it's because your string doesn't *actually* end with a comma. When you run:

```
str = "hello,"
print str.rstrip(",")

str = "hello,\n"
print str.rstrip(",")
print str.rstrip(",\n")
```

the output is:

```
hello
hello,

hello
```

In other words, if there's a newline at the end of the string as well as a comma, you'll need to `rstrip` both characters with `",\n"`.

---

Okay, based on your comment, here's what you're trying:

```
uptime = subprocess.Popen([r"uptime"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
uptime_stdout = uptime.communicate()[0]
print uptime_stdout
awk = subprocess.Popen([r"awk", "{print $11}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
awk_stdin = awk.communicate(uptime_stdout)[0]
print repr(awk_stdin)
temp = awk_stdin
tem = temp.rstrip("\n")
logfile = open('/usr/src/python/uptime.log', 'a')
logfile.write(tem + "\n")
logfile.close()
```

What are you actually *getting* from your two `print` statements and what is being appended to the log file?

My particular `uptime` doesn't *have* a `$11`:

```
23:43:10 up  5:10,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

but yours may be different.

Still, we need to see the output of your script.

Comment: surely, you're not suggesting that built-in method stopped working?

Comment: No, but there's info missing from the question. I answered the "how do i strip comma from the end of an string?"

Comment: uptime = subprocess.Popen([r"uptime"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
uptime_stdout = uptime.communicate()[0]
print uptime_stdout

awk = subprocess.Popen([r"awk", "{print $11}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
awk_stdin = awk.communicate(uptime_stdout)[0]
print repr(awk_stdin)
temp = awk_stdin
tem = temp.rstrip("\n")
logfile = open('/usr/src/python/uptime.log', 'a')
logfile.write(tem + "\n")
logfile.close()

this is what i am trying to do

Comment: thats the value, just after load average:

Comment: Then surely that would be `$8`, not `$11` - you really need to post the output of your script if you want this solved. It does little good for us to guess at what might be wrong when a little more info will almost certainly pinpoint it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all commas at the end of the string:

```
str = '1234,,,'
str = str.rstrip(',')
```

Comment: I think you may have meant `str.rstrip(',')`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that `awk_stdin` actually ends with a newline (`print repr(awk_stdin)` to show it clearly), so you'll need to rstrip *that* away, before rstrip'ping the comma (or, you could do both at once with a RE, but the basic idea is that the comma *isn't* actually the last character in that string!-).

Answer (score 0):

If you have whitespace/non printing characters then try something like this:

```
a_string = 'abcdef,\n'
a_string.strip().rstrip(',') if a_string.strip().endswith(',') else a_string.strip()
```

saves you the trouble of checking string lengths and figuring out slice indexes.

Of course if you do not need to do anything different for strings that do not end in a comma then you could just do:

```
a_string.strip().rstrip(',')
```